# Use Chebyshev's inequality to find the parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, dice

We roll a symmetrical die $200$ times. $X$ is a random variable representing the number of the 6 face appearing. Using Chebyshev's inequality find $c>0$ so that the probability $$Pr(X\in(a-c, a+c))$$ is at least $0.85$.

My attempt:
$$Pr(a-c<X<a+c)\geq0.85$$
$$1-Pr(a-c<X<a+c)\leq1-0.85$$
$$1-Pr(|X-a|<c)\leq 0.15$$
$$Pr(|X-a|\geq c)\leq 0.15$$

$E[X]=200\cdot1/6,  \sigma^2=200\cdot5/36$

Now:
$$0.15=\frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$$
And from that we get $c>0$.

The thing is my colleague got an answer with $c$ being an interval. Now I'm not sure which one of our solutions is correct (or maybe neither is).

Comment: You are supposed to find a number for $c$ so $(a-c, a+c)$ is an interval

Comment: Yes, but my friend got a following answer: $0 <c \leq 50 \sqrt{2/17}/3$. Now, that you emphasized it would be kind of weird if $c$ wasn't a fixed value because what would it mean for the interval $(a-c, a+c)$? That's covnvincing me that my solution might be correct.

Comment: If you know $\sigma^2$ and if $0.15=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$ then you can find $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define variable
$$
X_n = \Big\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & else\\
1 & dice=6
\end{array}
$$
Then $\mathbf{E}X_n = P(X_n=6) = \frac{1}{6} \ \mathbf{E}X_n^2 = \frac{1}{6}, \mathbf{Var}X_n = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6^2} = \frac{5}{36}$. Now define
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{200}X_k
$$
Combine them. and from this you can find $\mathbf{E}S_n$ and $\mathbf{Var}S_n$. Now, I assume $a$ in your example is $\mathbf{E}S_n$. In such case,
$$
P(c + a \leq S_n \leq -c +a) = P(|S_n - a|<c) = 1-P(|S_n - a|>c) \geq 1- \frac{\mathbf{Var} S_n}{c^2} \geq 0.85
$$

Now solve for $c$, keep in mind $c>0$.

Comment: $c$ is an interval, then?

Comment: $c$ is an upper bound on a distance between $S_n$ and $a$